# Use VMware extension on Azure DevOps with Java 11

Tags: java, azure-devops, vmware, java-11

I have followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/vmware?view=azure-devops) to set up Azure DevOps to revert a snapshot with the [VMware extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vmwareapp).

I managed to get it working with vSphere Management SDK 7.0 U3f and adding Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_221) to the path-variable of Windows.

But now we want to install Visual Studio 2022 on the agent. But because of Visual Studio 2022 installing Microsoft Build of OpenJDK with Hotspot 11 in the path-variable, I have to get it working with this version of Java. According to the release notes, SDK 7.0 U3f should support Java 11.

Azure DevOps generates this command:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe -classpath vmOpsTool-1.0.jar;C:\vSphereSDK\SDK\vsphere-ws\java\JAXWS\lib\vim25.jar VmOpsTool -snapshotOps restore -snapshotName DeploymentReadySnapshot -timeout 60 -vCenterUrl https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/sdk/vimService -vCenterUserName *** -vCenterPassword *** -vmList VM-DPL-001 -targetdc BuildManagement -skipca true
```

And this is the output:

```
2023-06-02T10:50:33.3249971Z Parsing input parameters...
2023-06-02T10:50:33.3342795Z Checking for active session...
2023-06-02T10:50:33.3345005Z No active session found.. establishing new session.
2023-06-02T10:50:34.3238705Z java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/ws/Service
```

How can I get the SDK working with Java 11?